# Url from form using php

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to create a link to include variables from a form.
The script below works put only includes the first variable:
`http://example.com/abc.php?id=2`

I want it to send:
`http://example.com/abc.php?id=2&name=zac`

PHP code shown below:

```
$base = 'http://example.com/abc.php';
$id=$_GET['ID'];
$name=$_GET['Name'];

$data = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name,
);

$url = $base . '?' . http_build_query($data);

header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Are you trying to redirect to a different URL with the same query string? Or do you need to select specific parameters from the query string?

Comment: I would guess that one of those items is undefined. `$id=$_GET['ID'];` there are no checks on this or the other one.

Comment: The shown snippet seems to be working: https://3v4l.org/cASEB - until `$_GET['Name']` is null or undefined: https://3v4l.org/b9EVM

Comment: `$_GET['Name']` must not be set. Are you sure the index is correct?

Comment: `$name=$_GET['Name'] ??  '';`  You could dare I say also look at `$_SERVER` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`  but that won't fix the undefined issues.

Comment: I have checked and it definitely is defined but still doesn’t show

Comment: I’ve even tried defining the ID twice but even that doesn’t show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your life a bit easier by just sending the form via `$_GET` and it will redirect to the URL like you're wanting. Here's an example:

```
<form action="http://example.com/abc.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="ID" />
  <input type="text" name="Name" />
</form>
```

This would send the user to: http://example.com/abc.php?ID=id_value&Name=name_value

**Note:** This will send all form variables with a value set.

Comment: I would do it like this but I need it as a link before submitting the form